# Can anyone explain difference between /RU System and /RU Users and in which scenarios we can use those for scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to understand what is the basic difference between /RU SYSTEM and /RU USERS .And what significance it has in scheduled tasks.

Comment: Create both tasks and have a look at the task scheduler to see the difference. One will be run as the System user. The GUI also has some information on that I believe.

Comment: One is coming with user account 'System' and one with 'Users' account. How both are different from each other in terms of privileges and rights?       And /RU System task would 'run whether user logged in or not' whether its the reverse for /RU Users. If I don't give /RU Users it would come with 'Administrator' user account . How it is different from trail one?

Comment: @RongaliRamunaidu [How the System account is used in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/120929/how-the-system-account-is-used-in-windows)

Comment: @RongaliRamunaidu [LocalSystem Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx)